# Workbook Skipping blank cell

Tags: java, excel

I am trying to read  an excel file(xls) file using Workbook that, during read row if a cell is blank (cellIterator) is skipping that cell and putting the next value to different header.
Here is full **java** code and I am using **cellIterator**

```
public  Vector<Vector<Cell>> ReadCSV(String filename) {
    Vector cellVectorHolder = new Vector();

    try {
        FileInputStream myInput = new FileInputStream(filename);
        LoginServlet.logger.info("Input:"+myInput);
        Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(myInput);

        Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

        Iterator rowIter = sheet.rowIterator();

        while (rowIter.hasNext()) {
            Row myRow = (Row) rowIter.next();
            Iterator cellIter = myRow.cellIterator();
            Vector cellStoreVector = new Vector();
            while (cellIter.hasNext()) {
                Cell myCell = (Cell) cellIter.next();
                cellStoreVector.addElement(myCell);
            }
            cellVectorHolder.addElement(cellStoreVector);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    return cellVectorHolder;
}
```